# Continuing a TikZ animation with \onslide after a \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, loops

I want to produce an animation in a tikzpicture environment in Beamer. The animation consists in a series of slides produced by combining `\foreach` and `\onslide`, which works fine. I then want to continue my animation with a few more slides produced by `\onslide` but not within the `\foreach` command. But the compilation gets stuck for some reason.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{3}
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,\N}{
    \onslide<\n>{
        \draw (0,0) node {node on slide \n};
    }
}
\onslide<\N+1>{
    \draw (0,0) node {node on slide {\N+1}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem stems from `\onslide<\N+1>`. Substituting `\onslide<4>` for that works fine. For maintainability reasons, though, I don't want to hardcode the slide number. In order to solve the problem, I've tried to surround \N+1 with braces:

`\onslide<{\N+1}>`

to no avail; the following code also doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{3}
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,\N}{
    \onslide<\n>{
        \draw (0,0) node {node on slide \n};
    }
}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{\N+1}
\onslide<\n>{
    \draw (0,0) node {node on slide {\N+1}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\pgfmathsetmacro` inserts a decimal so that `\N` is defined to be `3.0` and that wreaks havoc in the inital frame content readout. If you want to define integers, either `\def`ine it or use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\N}{3}
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,\N}{
    \onslide<\n>{
        \draw (0,0) node {node on slide \n};
    }
}
\pgfmathparse{int(\N+1)}
\onslide<\pgfmathresult>{
    \draw (0,0) node {node on slide {\number\numexpr\N+1\relax}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jubobs My pleasure.