# Drawing TikZ pictures step by step for beamer slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, foreach

I want to uncover/draw a picture bit by bit for `beamer` slides. I imagined that using `\only` inside a `\foreach` loop should work, for instance:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle}]
      \node (n0) {$0$};
      \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using \i-1] in {1,...,3} {%
        \only<\i->{%
          \node[right of=n\j] (n\i) {$\i$};
        }
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, two problems occur.

- Something goes wrong with node names; I get errors of the form

  ```
  Package pgf Error: No shape named n0.0 is known.
  ```
- When using `\j` in the parameter of `\only`, I get hundreds of errors and pages.

What is going on here?

Comment: While I managed to solve the issue at hand (by collecting stuff from other tex.SE posts) I'd appreciate answers that shed more light on the situation. Is this a bug, or does `evaluate` work as intended and I used it wrong?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131892/21891

Comment: You would have solved your issue with `\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i-1)]`; see [percusse's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/hobby-path-realization-in-convex-hull-approach#comment175638_76454).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Ah, that's way more elegant of course. Would you mind adding this as an answer?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99701/continuing-a-tikz-animation-with-onslide-after-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @Raphael: as you already provided an answer, you might split it into two parts: one with your previous method and on with the one you just learned. :)

Comment: Please see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

Comment: This has already been discussed here just not for beamer overlays. Possible duplicate: [How to decrease the counter in tikz foreach loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110376)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel While some of the solutions carry over, the problem is not the same (to the user). An important part of this question is that using `evaluate` variables with `only`, bad stuff happens. I think that should be searchable.

Comment: It isn’t? I’d say the problem is the same, the symptom is not. You’re using `<0.0->`, `<1.0->` and so on for the overlays. Using `int`, `count` or `remember` (with `initially` here) works for me for the overlays, too. Either way, it is linked now and can be found. `:)` By the way, you can also say `\node<\i-1> …`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Call it symptom, if you will; the fact remains, somebody experiencing the symptom has a hard time finding a solution. I know I did (you may check [this search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=beamer+only+tikz+loop) or similar; many results lead to unrelated questions) and that's why I added this question. (If you consider only underlying problems, most questions likely are duplicates, aren't they? ;))

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks about the note regarding positioning. That's what happens if there's lots of old stuff on the net, I guess. :/

Comment: I hope that this question will not be deleted because it's closed. The linked question does *not* provide a good search target for people that experience the symptoms I did.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `evaluate` does not produce integers but floats (the error message hints thus). Using

```
\def\j{\the\numexpr\i-1\relax}
```

instead (inside the loop, of course) computes `\j` in the desired way and solves both problems.

PGF has some macros that make this nicer;

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i-1}
```

has the same effect.

The most elegant way, however, has been proposed by [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino):

```
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i-1)]
```